# SQL 'AS' keyword added when upgrading from EntityFrameworkCore 2.1 and breaking code

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been at this for days and am ready to give up.

I have inherited a .NET Core project that was using 2.1, including EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.

I have an EF query in the code that throws an exception whenever I touch the version number (I've tried to go 2.2, but even tried 2.1.11 and even 2.1.1!)

`SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.`

So I decided to look at the console logs of what statement is going to run and I can see a single difference, that is only appearing when I update EntityFrameworkCore, but can't find anything on the net to document this or help me.

Original query starts like this:

```
SELECT [WebsiteCategory].[CategoryID], [WebsiteCategory].[WebSiteID], CASE
    WHEN [t].[Name] IS NULL OR ([t].[Name] = N'')
    THEN [WebsiteCategory.Category].[Category] ELSE [t].[Name]
```

After upgrading (even just to 2.1.1) I see this

```
SELECT [WebsiteCategory].[CategoryID], [WebsiteCategory].[WebSiteID], CASE
    WHEN [t].[Name] AS [Name0] IS NULL OR ([t].[Name] AS [Name0] = N'')
    THEN [WebsiteCategory.Category].[Category] ELSE [t].[Name] AS [Name0]
```

The change is a mysterious `AS [Name0]` appearing out of nowhere!

Unfortunately my SQL isn't too strong, I have only ever really had to use basic SELECT queries as most of my development has been using EntityFramework.

Any ideas? This is blocking us upgrading to 2.2 and I am worried it will mean we just never upgrade EntityFramework again!

EDIT: The Linq query is

```cs
return _productRepository.Context.WebSiteCategory
    .GroupJoin(_productRepository.Context.CategoryTranslations
                                         .Where(z => z.Locale == culture.Name),
        WebsiteCategory => WebsiteCategory.CategoryId,
        Translation => Translation.CategoryId,
        (x, y) => new { WebsiteCategory = x, Translation = y })
    .SelectMany(
        xy => xy.Translation.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, Translation) => new { x.WebsiteCategory, Translation })
    .Select(s => new
                {
                    s.WebsiteCategory,
                    s.Translation
                })
                .Where(x => websiteIds.Contains(x.WebsiteCategory.WebSiteId))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.WebsiteCategory.CategoryId,
                    x.WebsiteCategory.WebSiteId,
                    x.WebsiteCategory.Category.Category,
                    x.Translation.Name,
                    x.WebsiteCategory.Category.CategorySeo,
                    x.WebsiteCategory.Category.Order
                })
    .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    x.CategoryId,
                    x.WebSiteId,
                    x.Category,
                    x.Name,
                    x.CategorySeo,
                    x.Order
                })
    .Select(x => new ProductCategoryDTO
                {
                    CategoryId = x.Key.CategoryId,
                    WebSiteId = x.Key.WebSiteId,
                    Category = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key.Name) ? x.Key.Category : x.Key.Name,
                    CategorySEO = x.Key.CategorySeo,
                    Order = x.Key.Order
                })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you show the sample LINQ query? It could be a bug / problem related to the query pattern, but in order to be more specific, I need to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: added - but i dont get why it would work in 2.1 and not any version higher!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with similar LINQ query shape. The problem is caused by the expression

```
  string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key.Name) ? x.Key.Category : x.Key.Name
```

after `GroupBy`. The actual type of the expression is not essential, it seems to happen with any expression other than property access or aggregate method.

Apparently it's EF Core regression bug. All I can say is that they are constantly working on query translation, and for sure on `GroupBy` optimizations. However along with the improvements unfortunately they introduce regressions. And there is nothing you can do until (and if) they fix it other than looking for a workaround.

The workaround is to avoid such expressions after `GroupBy` by preselecting them in advance or embedding them into `GroupBy` key. For instance, changing your sample query to

```
.GroupBy(x => new
{
    x.CategoryId,
    x.WebSiteId,
    Category = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) ? x.Category : x.Name, // <--
    x.Name,
    x.CategorySeo,
    x.Order
})
.Select(x => new ProductCategoryDTO
{
    CategoryId = x.Key.CategoryId,
    WebSiteId = x.Key.WebSiteId,
    Category = x.Key.Category, // <--
    CategorySEO = x.Key.CategorySeo,
    Order = x.Key.Order
})
```

Comment: absolute hero. you just saved my Sunday afternoon :) This is precisely the issue, and I can see through a more pinpointed google search that MS are aware of this and plan to fix it in 3.0.